# Connections for windup key holes?

Tags: compatibility, connections

I recently bought a set with a Windup Key ([piece 29979/79812](https://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-windup-key-29979-79812)) and took note of its holes since they're slightly smaller than the standard rod / minifig accessory diameter.

[image]

After an (admittedly brief) look through my own pieces, I couldn't find anything that fit perfectly in them. The closest I could find are minifig hands, though the holes are slightly too large for them.

This made me curious: are there any legal connections for the windup key's holes?